# SimpleDateFormat bug parsing noon?

Tags: java, date

After an infuriating session with the debugger I appear to have found a bug in SimpleDateParser.

The code:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

My debugger session:

```
formatter.parse("2013-09-20 10:23:45.123")
Fri Sep 20 10:23:45 BST 2013

formatter.parse("2013-09-20 11:23:45.123")
Fri Sep 20 11:23:45 BST 2013

formatter.parse("2013-09-20 12:23:45.123")
Fri Sep 20 00:23:45 BST 2013

formatter.parse("2013-09-20 13:23:45.123")
Fri Sep 20 13:23:45 BST 2013

formatter.parse("2013-09-20 14:23:45.123")
Fri Sep 20 14:23:45 BST 2013

formatter.parse("2013-09-20 00:23:45.123")
Fri Sep 20 00:23:45 BST 2013
```

Am I going crazy? Can there really be a bug in something this basic in Java?

Java 1.6.0_43

Comment: I don't get the same output as yours: `Fri Sep 20 12:23:45 CEST 2013`.

Comment: I get the correct output too: http://ideone.com/BYgbhD

Comment: If this were iOS I'd suspect some variation on the locale 12/24 "feature".

Comment: Assuming the output is generated by Date.toString(), what is the output of getTime() for the third and the last date?

Comment: You should not use DateFormats without specifying the locale.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the format in the question or did you rewrite it? I mean that if the true format was `hh:mm:ss` instead of `HH:mm:ss`, this would be a normal behavior

Answer (score 5):

Works on my machine...

imho, it's a problem of locale. In a AM/PM system, 12:32 is probably parsed as 00:32.

Can you test :

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.FRENCH);
```

**Another solution** :

I don't know if you recopied the date format or if you copy-pasted it in your question but if the format is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS` (with lower-case `hh`), this behavior is normal. Use `HH` instead.

Comment: This should really be a comment

Comment: I use comments as much as possible but I sincerely think that this is the correct answer.

Comment: I don't think so: if it would be AM/PM system, it wouldn't parse properly 13 and 14 hours.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Fair enough - the first iteration of this really did just sound like `can you try`?

Comment: HH is giving in 24 hour format i need to get in 12 hour format

Comment: @KrunalShah Use 'hh' for the 12h format and use 'a' to have the am/pm marker.

Comment: yes i already done with this, but for "am"  i need to display "00" instead of "12"